# Failed in "make" command in compiling android source

Tags: android, android-source, rom

Hy... I'm building an android ROM from source. I have successfully executed source build/envsetup.sh then lunch. Then for the last, I'm facing some errors in "make". These are the errors :

```
*Checking API : checkapi-last
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:23512:error 12: Class android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager changed static qualifier
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23496: error 9: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.divideMessage
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23497: error 9: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.getDefault
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23498: error 9: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendDataMessage
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23499: error 9: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23500: error 9: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.sendTextMessage
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23501: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23502: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23503: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23504: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23505: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.STATUS_ON_SIM_FREE
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23506: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_SIM_READ
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23507: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_SIM_SENT
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23508: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_SIM_UNREAD
prebuilts/sdk/api/19.txt:23509: error 10: Removed public method android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_SIM_UNSENT*
```

I have searched on google how to solve these errors, but they said that it's just about the java. Then I checked my java and javac, they already have them same java version namely 1.6.0_45. So I think, java is not my problem here...
Another solution is to use *make update-api* && make, but that still doesn't solve my problem...

Can anyone wanna to help me solving this problem...???
Thanks in advance..?? :-)

Comment: what version of android are you trying to build ?

Comment: I'm using android-4.4_r1.2.0.1....

Answer (score 1):

which aosp version do you make? 
if you make android 2.3.1 , please make sure your javadoc version is 6.
or the same version as javac and java.
sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc
and don't forget clean the folder:
rm -rf out/target/common/docs/

now, try to make again

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a source tree (or did it yourself) that has a modified API than the one declared for AOSP (or that previous custom build that you branched from).

You should search in the source tree for those android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager.* declarations. If you delete them from the txt files that list the API, you will get to build your own non-AOSP compatible image. Packed with possibly unforeseen disabled functionality, like no SMS support, as i guess from the log message.

Comment: I have found those error messages in file 19.txt. Ummm... Ok... I'm gonna try to delete all of those error messages... Thanks Mr.Bogdan V....

Comment: Waaaw... Cool... It works Mr.Bogdan V, the error is gone, but the new error comes... :D

Ummm... Thanks.... :-)

Comment: Welcome to the magnificent terror of non-standardized android building. You are doing your own port of Android. Next step, buy a new phone and do your own Android port for it :).

Comment: Hehehe.... :D ....until now compiling is Ok.I hope everything is good until it's finished..and oowh... I already have nexus 7 (wifi only)... ;-)..and I hope again that I don't ruin that nexus hihihihi... :D